# What is the wrong with my java code, its not clearing all the tests?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Though the problem is easy. Here it is :

Problem Statement

Password security is a very important topic today. We define a password system here as a set of requirements that a valid password in this system must fulfill. In each such system every valid password consists only of digits [0−9]. In addition, for each such system there are two requirements which a valid password must fulfill:

Minimum length of a valid password.

Maximum length of a valid password.

We say that a password system is secure if and only if there are more than one million (106) different possible passwords in this system. Your task, as a security expert, is to decide for a given password system if it is secure.

Note

- Repetition of digits are allowed. That is 111 is a valid password of length 3.
- Leading 0's are allowed. That is 001 and 000 are valid password of length 3.
- You have to consider the sum of all passwords whose length lies in range of minimum and maximum value. That is
  if minimum length is 3 and maximum length is 5, then you have to find
  total count of passwords whose length are either 3, 4 or 5.

  Input Format

  In the first line there is a single integer, T, denoting the number of test cases.

  T lines follow.

  The ith line denotes a single test case and describes a given password system. It consists of two integers, m and M, denoting the minimum password length and the maximum password length in this system.

Constraints

1≤T≤100

1≤m≤M≤10

Output Format

Print exactly T lines. In the ith of them print "YES" (without quotes) if the ith password system is secure, otherwise print "NO" (without quotes).

Sample Input

```
2
5 5
7 8
```

Sample Output

```
 NO
 YES
```

Explanation

```
Sample Case #00

All valid passwords have length 5, hence there are exactly 100000 different passwords; this system in insecure, because we need more than a million different passwords for a system to be secure.


Sample Case #01

We are allowed to have passwords of length 7 or 8 and since there are more than a million different such passwords, this system is secure.
```

My Understanding:  Since repetition is allowed we have to compute 10^m to 10^M and sum them through. But if M >= 6 we dont have to compute directly we can say "YES" and if M <= 5 we can say "NO" directly.

Here is my code :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cases = scan.nextInt();
        int minl = 0, maxl = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++){
            minl = 0;
            maxl = 0;
            sum = 0;
            minl = scan.nextInt();
            maxl = scan.nextInt();
                if(maxl >= 6){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }else if(maxl <= 5){
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }else if(minl >= 6){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }else if((maxl - minl) >= 6){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }else{
                for(double k = minl; k <= maxl; k++){
                    sum += Math.pow(10.0 , k);

                }

                if(sum >= 1000000){
                    System.out.println("YES" );
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
              }     

            }
        }
    }
```

And the code is failing to clear all the tests. Alas!

Comment: Which test is your code failing?

Comment: Test cases are not public. I feel I have covered all the cases but this one  clears only 2 test cases and fails in other 6 cases. Serious flaw in the logic it seems.

Comment: Could you clarify that? I'm not sure what you mean by "test cases". Your code seems to satisfy the conditions that you have listed. Side question: are you sure that maxl is larger than minl?

Comment: On some websites you can submit code and they will test them for test cases, that is they will give various inputs to check the code and check the result generated by the code. if it matches with pre-computed results your code is okay otherwise wrong.

Comment: You do realize that `maxl>=6` and `maxl<=5` exhausts all the possibilities?

Comment: If someone came to you and said a test case is failing, would your first question be, which one????

Comment: @ Teepeemm Yes but not fully, I guess that's why I am making mistake. 10^6 is 1 million and 10^5 is less than million

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson Sorry to have caused any agony.

Comment: Did they (H*) give you sample input and expected output?

Comment: @ Teepeemm so if I remove everything apart from that it should clear the all the test cases but its not.

Comment: @Thinkingcap I have updated the question with sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement says to print YES "if and only if there are **more than** one million different possible passwords in this system."

It looks like your code is checking for more than or equal to with `if(maxl >= 6)`.

Comment: Kindly clarify on that!!

Comment: more than one million would be `if(maxl > 6)`

Comment: if minl=1 and maxl=6  then count would be greater than million (1,111,110)  anyways , I don't understand how that solved your problem!

Comment: See for maxl=6 the value of Math.pow(10.0, 6) is 10^6 already but the since minl = 1, we need to sum all the successive values from 10^1 to 10^6 and the problem statement clearly says that for a password to be secure we need to have more than one million different possible passwords as pointed by @spinach. Hence it solves the problem.  In my case I was checking maxl >= 6 but the problem statement clearly stated that the minimum variations in the password system should be more than that. Hence just by altering the greater than or equal to ">=" to greater than ">" cleared the test cases.

Comment: You are right 1 and 6 should pass test case and for that only at the end in the last else we are doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++){
    minl = 0;
    maxl = 0;
    minl = scan.nextInt();
    maxl = scan.nextInt();
    if(maxl > 6 || (maxl == 6 && minl <6)){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is simple. Thanks this is better than my solution.